# What i the reaction of an alkene with cold, dilute, neutral potassium permanganate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons

How will an alkene react with *dilute, cold, neutral* $\ce{KMnO4}$?

Comment: @YashasSamaga We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of $\ce{KMnO4}$ in a neutral medium is nearly the same as its behaviour in slightly alkaline medium.

In alkaline medium:

$\ce{3R-CH=CH-R + 2MnO4- + 2OH- -> R-CH(OH)-CH(OH)-R + MnO4^2-}$

In neutral medium:

$\ce{3R-CH=CH-R + 2MnO4- + 4H2O -> R-CH(OH)-CH(OH)-R + MnO2 + 2OH-}$

Comment: Wow, interesting. I wasn't expecting that. Thank you for your help!